# TypeScript partial interface object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In React, the [Component definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react.d.ts#L161) looks something like this:

```
class Component<S> {
    state:S;
    setState(state:S):void;
}
```

And you define a component like this:

```
interface MyState {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
class MyComponent extends Component<MyState> { }
```

Now the issue I have is that in the React API `setState` is supposed to be called with a *partial* state object, representing properties to be updated, like this:

```
setState({name: "Aaron"});
```

Note that `age` is not declared. The problem I have is that TypeScript doesn't allow this, it gives an assignment error like `Property 'age' is missing`. By my understanding, the `react.d.ts` definition is wrong in this sense. But is there a solution?

I tried this:

```
setState({name: "Aaron"} as MyState);
```

But this gives the same error, even though it [works in the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Component%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%09state%3A%20T%3B%0A%09setState(state%3AT)%3Avoid%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20MyState%20%7B%0A%09name%3A%20string%3B%0A%09age%3A%20number%3B%0A%09location%3A%20Location%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MyComponent%20extends%20Component%3CMyState%3E%20%7B%0A%09test()%20%7B%0A%09%09this.setState(%7Bname%3A%20%22Test%22%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%0A%09%09this.setState(%7Bname%3A%20%22Test%22%7D%20as%20MyState)%3B%20%2F%2F%20no%20error%20here%2C%20but%20error%20in%20my%20local%20build%3F%0A%09%7D%0A%7D) without giving an error. Why does it work in the Playground? Any ideas?

Comment: I somehow managed to get partial types working with `Object.assign` (fully working with type-checking and without having to create interface declarations with optional members), but I'm still unsure how. The very same code works in one project but not in another. Once I figure it out I'll post the update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `react.d.ts` definition is indeed wrong, and cannot be fixed until [Partial Types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4889) are supported.

The problem is that `setState` takes a partial state, which is a different type from normal state. You can solve this by manually specifying both types:

```
interface MyState {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

interface PartialMyState {
    name?: string;
    age?: number;
}
```

And manually declaring `MyComponent` without extending the provided React `Component` class:

```
class MyComponent {
    state: MyState;
    setState(state:PartialMyState): void;
    //...
}
```

Which means you'll have to duplicate these function definitions for every subclass of `Component` in your code. You may be able to avoid this by defining a correct `Component` class generalized by an additional type of partial state:

```
class CorrectComponent<S,P> { // generalized over both state and partial state
    state:S;
    setState(state:P):void;
    //...
}

class MyComponent extends CorrectComponent<MyState,PartialMyState> { }
```

You'll still have to write a partial version for every state type you have.

---

Alternatively, you can make `setState` non-typesafe by changing its argument's type to `Object`.

Answer (score 28):

<strike>"Partial types" are still missing in TypeScript currently, see [TypeScript issue #4889](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4889) as well as [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33704506/1321716). I'm afraid it's not yet possible to make this type-check correctly.</strike>

You *might* get away with marking all fields of your `MyState` interface as optional (by adding `?` modifiers), but that in turn weakens the type-checking for things like `Component.state` (where you want *all* fields to be set).

**EDIT (December 2016):** TypeScript 2.1 introduces [mapped types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#mapped-types), which supports describing [partial types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#partial-readonly-record-and-pick) using `Partial<T>`! Now you can use the following type definition for `Component`:

```
class Component<S> {
    state: S;
    setState(state: Partial<S>) : void;
}
```

Comment: Only to give an example of the given workaround, in your case, your interface would be: `interface MyState {
    name?: string;
    age?: number;
}`

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I was avoiding marking all fields as optional because it's not really true... any idea why my Playground example works? It seems like it should not?

Comment: @Aaron That example works because the `as MyState` acts as an override for the type checker. Still, I don't see how the same code would fail in your local build...

Comment: @MattiasBuelens It seems to have something to do with optional properties. [See here.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20MyStateA%20%7B%0A%09name%3A%20string%3B%0A%09age%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20MyStateB%20%7B%0A%09name%3F%3A%20string%3B%0A%09age%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20setA(a%3AMyStateA)%3Avoid%20%7B%7D%0A%0Afunction%20setB(a%3AMyStateB)%3Avoid%20%7B%7D%0A%0AsetA(%7Bname%3A%20%22Aaron%22%7D%20as%20MyStateA)%3B%20%2F%2F%20no%20error%0AsetB(%7Bname%3A%20%22Aaron%22%7D%20as%20MyStateB)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%3F) What is the difference here?

Comment: @MattiasBuelens I've accepted this answer, however I'm still confused why `interface S {a: string; b: string};` works with `let s:S = {a:"hi"} as S;`, but if I make `a` optional, like `interface S { a?: string; b: string}`, then it gives an error on assignment/assertion that `b` is missing?

Answer (score 1):

As other people have stated, since TypeScript 2.1, the [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) keyword has been implemented.

However for future readers, it is worth noting the difference in syntax between Interfaces and Types when extending them.

For Interfaces:

```js
interface MyState {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

interface MyStatePartial extends Partial<MyState> {}
// Results in:
// {
//     name?: string;
//     age?: number;
// }
```

Note the reason for the empty curly braces (`{}`) at the end is because I'm extending the interface, but not adding any new keys ([See Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types))

For Types:

```js
type MyState = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

type MyStatePartial = Partial<MyState>;
```

Note: If you want similar syntax to the interface version you could do:

```js
type MyStatePartial = Partial<MyState> & {};
```

Which, while redundant does allow the reader to see the syntactical similarities between Types and Interfaces