# Why does TypeScript assertion of object literal `{a}` work with interface `{a, b}` but not `{a?, b}`

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Why does the following assertion work:

```
interface AllRequired {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

let all = {a: "foo"} as AllRequired; // No error
```

But this assertion gives an error:

```
interface SomeOptional {
    a?: string;
    b: string;
}

let some = {a: "foo"} as SomeOptional; // Error: Property 'b' missing
```

The only difference I can see is making one of the interface properties optional (`?`). It seems that if all properties are not optional, I can assert a partial object to the interface, but as soon as any of the interface properties are optional, I cannot assert a partial object anymore. This doesn't really make sense to me and I've been unable to find an explanation of this behavior. What's going on here?

---

For context: I [encountered this behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36633639/typescript-partial-interface-object/36634231) while trying to work around the problem that React's `setState()` takes a partial state object, but [TypeScript doesn't yet have partial types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4889) to make this work properly with your state interface. As a workaround I came up with `setState({a: "a"} as MyState)` and found this works as long as interface `MyState` fields are *all* non-optional, but fails as soon as *some* properties are optional. (Making all properties optional is a workaround, but very undesirable in my case. )

Comment: to be honest I think there's only one person on stackoverflow able to respond to that question and that's @RyanCavanaugh (hopefully that will summon him). Otherwise there might be an issue about on the TypeScript github page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type assertions can only be used to convert between a type and a subtype of it.

Let's say you declared the following variables:

```
declare var foo: number | string;
declare var bar: number;
```

Note `number` is a *subtype* of `number | string`, meaning any value that matches the type `number` (e.g. `3`) also matches `number | string`. Therefore, it is allowed to use type assertions to convert between these types:

```
bar = foo as number; /* convert to subtype */
foo = bar as number | string; /* convert to supertype (assertion not necessary but allowed) */
```

Similarly, `{ a: string, b: string }` is a subtype of `{ a: string }`. Any value that matches `{ a: string, b: string }` (e.g. `{ a: "A", b: "B" }`) also matches `{ a: string }`, because it has an `a` property of type `string`.

In contrast, neither of `{ a?: string, b: string }` or `{ a: string }` is a subtype of the other.
Some values (e.g. `{ b: "B" }`) match only the former, and others (e.g. `{ a: "A" }`) match only the latter.

If you *really* need to convert between unrelated types, you can work around this by using a common supertype (such as `any`) as an intermediate:

```
let foo = ({ a: "A" } as any) as { a?: string, b: string };
```

---

The relevant part in the spec is [4.16 Type Assertions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/28840863a635b6803505a821bcb18d9638c38012/doc/spec.md#4.16):

> In a type assertion expression of the form < T > e, e is contextually typed (section 4.23) by T and the resulting type of *e* is required to be assignable to T, or T is required to be assignable to the widened form of the resulting type of e, or otherwise a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is only a theory but I have some code to back it up.

In your first example, when casting to `AllRequired` you're basically saying to the compiler the you know what you're doing and you'll set the value for `all.b` later on.

In the second example you think you're doing the same but the compiler probably thinks "hey, if he sets the optional property he must be setting a full object" and so it's confused as for why the value for `some.b` is missing from this full object.

This may sound a bit far fetched, but here:

```
let some2 = (all.a ? {a: "foo"} : {}) as SomeOptional
```

The error is gone if you use a condition because then (well, probably) `some2.a` is really optional.

Try it in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20AllRequired%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20all%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%20%22foo%22%7D%20as%20AllRequired%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20SomeOptional%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20some%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%20%22foo%22%7D%20as%20SomeOptional%3B%0D%0Alet%20some2%20%3D%20(all.a%20%3F%20%7Ba%3A%20%22foo%22%7D%20%3A%20%7B%7D)%20as%20SomeOptional%3B).

Comment: Well the assertion fails if you pass a required props partial too, ex `interface {a?:string, b:string, c:string}` can't assert `{b:"hi"}`, but if make `a` non-optional (so *all* are required) then the *same* assertion works. It's like the mere presence of an optional field kicks the assertion into a *stricter* check.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, your example works without an error (assigning `{b:"hi"}` doesn't have an error), but if I add `a: "yo"` then there's the error again, which can be explained with what I proposed.

Comment: You're right, I thought that `{b} as {a?, b, c}` doesn't work, but in fact it only doesn't work if it includes an optional param, like `{a, b} as {a?, b, c}`, but `{a, b} as {a, b, c}` does work. So the common aspect is providing an *optional* property makes the compiler want *all* non-optional properties, or something. I'm not sure I understand what's going on in your ternary example, it seems to let complete garbage through like `(true ? {a: 123, abc: "foo"} : {}) as SomeOptional` which is a completely messed up statement and value (`a` is wrong type, `abc` doesn't exist)...

Comment: But this `(true ? {a: 123, abc: "foo"} : { a: "hey" })  as SomeOptional` won't work. Basically it seems that if you include an optional field in the first assignment then the compiler demands that you include all the non optional ones.

Comment: Hm, `(true ? {a: 123, abc: "foo"} : {a: "hey"})` *does* catch "`abc` is not a prop" but it still fails to catch "`a` is not a number" as it normally would without the ternary. It seems that stuff on the left side of the ternary is doing something even more hap-hazard than the right-side or by itself... similar behavior appears using `||` operator... this is all very confusing to me!