# allow typescript compiler to call setState on only one react state property

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using Typescript with React for a project. The Main component gets passed state with this interface.

```
interface MainState {
  todos: Todo[];
  hungry: Boolean;
  editorState: EditorState;  //this is from Facebook's draft js
}
```

However, the code below (only an excerpt) won't compile.

```
class Main extends React.Component<MainProps, MainState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { todos: [], hungry: true, editorState: EditorState.createEmpty() };
  }
  onChange(editorState: EditorState) {
    this.setState({
      editorState: editorState
    });
  }
}
```

The compiler complains that, in the `onChange` method where I am only trying to setState for one property, the property `todos` and the property `hungry` is missing in type `{ editorState: EditorState;}`. In other words, I need to set the state of all three properties in the `onChange` function to make the code compile. For it to compile, I need to do

```
onChange(editorState: EditorState){
  this.setState({
    todos: [],
    hungry: false,
    editorState: editorState
  });
}
```

but there's no reason to set the `todos` and the `hungry` property at this point in the code. What is the proper way to call setState on only one property in typescript/react?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

#### Edit

The definitions for react were updated and the signature for `setState` are now:

```
setState<K extends keyof S>(state: Pick<S, K>, callback?: () => any): void;
```

Where `Pick<S, K>` is a built-in type which was added in Typescript 2.1:

```
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K]: T[P];
}
```

See [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) for more info.
If you still have this error then you might want to consider updating your react definitions.

#### Original answer:

I'm facing the same thing.

The two ways I manage to get around this annoying issue are:

(1) casting/assertion:

```
this.setState({
    editorState: editorState
} as MainState);
```

(2) declaring the interface fields as optional:

```
interface MainState {
    todos?: Todo[];
    hungry?: Boolean;
    editorState?: EditorState;
}
```

If anyone has a better solution I'd be happy to know!

---

#### Edit

While this is still an issue, there are two discussions on new features that will solve this problem:
[Partial Types (Optionalized Properties for Existing Types)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4889)
and
[More accurate typing of Object.assign and React component setState()](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6613)

Comment: I've given you an upvote for now. It compiles, but I Can't try your solution completely because I have other problems with my app (if you're feeling inspired there's another typescript Q here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302382/declaring-a-property-in-constructor-with-typescript-react) .  Regarding this answer you've provided, my only concern (which I'm sure probably isn't real or you would have mentioned it) is that your casting solution will set the other state properties to nil if they aren't explicitly set again, or does the casting just ignore it and leave them as they were?

Comment: No, react only updates the state with the properties you provided in the `setState`, if you haven't included a property then the previous value will stay

Comment: actually, I'm getting a runtime error `bundle.js:20184 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null`.  Not sure why `this` is null. It obviously seems unrelated to your solution, but until I can get it to work I have to wait to accept it as correct answer.

Comment: ok, had to bind the `onChange` function (for some reason) but got your solution to work. thank you.

Comment: Note that the assertion `as MainState` will only work if *all fields are not optional*. [I've explored this problem quite a bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36633639/typescript-partial-interface-object/36634231) and [haven't found a complete solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652622/why-does-typescript-assertion-of-object-literal-a-work-with-interface-a-b). TypeScript needs support for "partial objects" for it to work correctly.

Comment: New to typescript but I'm trying this helper method: `setState(s) {
        super.setState(s as MainState);
    }`

Comment: A little bit late, but I have this issue in addition with `strictNullChecks: true`. Most of my state entries are optional and TS doesn't look for default values neither for props, nor for state in the constructor. In result, all passed state values are marked as `not assignable`. It seems that I should make all optional state values to required and add casting. Better suggestions?

Comment: @RolandJegorov It would be better to see the code you're having problems with. Maybe ask a new question, you can refer to this question in it, but as your case is a bit different, and the code would help to understand your problem, it should be in a new question.

Answer (score 23):

Update state explicitly, example with the counter

```
this.setState((current) => ({ ...current, counter: current.counter + 1 }))
```

Comment: Hi, when I call setstate this way my state is updated asynchronously.  How do you handle it if you have multiple methods being run, each one updating the state an needing to see the state set by previous methods? on a field updatem for instance, I may call separate methods to 1. update the field  in the state 2. validate the new value , updating some error messages in the state, 3. set a dirtyFlag in the state. These methods need to know what the previous methods did to the state.  Is it best practice just to create a new state object in the very beginning of the event handler and just pass it

Comment: Using the Lambda setState will cause all setState to be run in serial in the order they where called, so as long as the setState that you are depending on was run before (as in the statement this.setState) the dependent one they will be applied in order ans the later will get the already updated state from the prior, no stale state.

Comment: will this `re-render all components` that has reference to any property of the `state` because you are spreading the `...state`?

Comment: When I do this, I get the error
`TypeScript error: Parameter 'state' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7006`

Answer (score 9):

I think that the best way to do it is to use `Partial`

Declare your component in the following way

```
class Main extends React.Component<MainProps, Partial<MainState>> {
}
```

Partial automatically changes all of the keys to optional.

Comment: What if you know they are defined? According to TS, they can _now_ be undefined. Now you need to explicitly tell TS it's okay via `property!`

Answer (score 3):

We can tell `setState` which field it should expect, by parametrising it with `<'editorState'>`:

```
this.setState<'editorState'>({
  editorState: editorState
});
```

If you are updating multiple fields, you can specify them like this:

```
this.setState<'editorState' | 'hungry'>({
  editorState: editorState,
  hungry: true,
});
```

although it will actually let you get away with specifying only one of them!

Anyway with the latest TS and `@types/react` both of the above are optional, but they lead us to...

---

If you want to use a **dynamic key**, then we can tell `setState` to expect no fields in particular:

```
this.setState<never>({
  [key]: value,
});
```

and as mentioned above, it doesn't complain if we pass an extra field.

([GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948))

Answer (score 1):

Edit: DO NOT USE this solution, prefer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41828633/1420794
See comments for details.

Now that spread operator has shipped in TS, my preferred solution is

```
this.setState({...this.state, editorState}); // do not use !
```

Comment: Holy crap, this is by far the easiest way. Please upvote this answer to give it more attention.

Comment: Still there's a downside for the moment ; TS won't detect if you're adding a property which wasn't declared (ie. misspelled). It should be resolved soon if I understood last design discussions of TS team =)

Comment: WARNING: DO NOT USE THIS SOLUTION!

If you do this, then you can have very hard to detect bugs because React batches the state updates.

Imagine something like this: `state = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }`, `coolSetState({ a: 2, b: 3 })`, `coolSetState({ c: 4 })` where `coolSetState = (editorState) => this.setState({...this.state, editorState})`

If the `coolSetState({ c: 4 })` is executed before the state got updated because of the previous operation, you might actually end up with `state ={ a: 1, b: 2, c: 4 }`

I used shorthand notations. Please let me know if I was being ambiguous.

Comment: you're right =s ! Best solution is @Alexey-Petrushin's I think

Answer (score 0):

I don't like casting and workarounds that gives you a lot place to make a mistake while you're scaling your project. Here'is my solution.

1. We have to get proper intellisense for key by using generic type

> `<K extends keyof MainState>`

2. Then, we have to get proper type for value based on entered key

> `typeof MainState[K]`

3. In order to get code without and an error and without using casting/workarounds etc, pass callback into `this.setState`
4. Combining all together

---

```
onChange = <K extends keyof MainState>(fieldName: K, value: typeof MainState[K]) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
                ...prevState,
                [fieldName]: value,
            };
        });
    };
```