# declaring a property in constructor with typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

From the draft-js documention, one can (in vanilla React, with no typescript) setup the Draft-js environment thus, noticing that the `onChange` property can be declared directly in the constructor:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Editor, EditorState} from 'draft-js';

class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};
    this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({editorState});
  }
  render() {
    const {editorState} = this.state;
    return <Editor editorState={editorState} onChange={this.onChange} />;
  }
}
```

However, when I try to do the same with Typescript/React (code below), I get this error

error TS2339: Property 'onChange' does not exist on type 'Main'.

```
class Main extends React.Component<MainProps, MainState> {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { todos: [], editorState: EditorState.createEmpty() };
    this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({ editorState });
  }
```

I also tried adding `onChange` as a property to the props

```
interface MainProps {
    model: Model;
    onChange: Function;
}
```

What is the appropriate way to declare such a function property in typescript/react?

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way instead of just have the `onChange` as a declared method of the class?

Comment: I tried declaring it as a method on the class (that's fine) but since the Draft-js docs showed a different example, I thought I'd try it, and wondered why it's not compiling with TypeScript.

Comment: Why don't you just declare the variable on `Main`?

Comment: @iberbeu `this.propertyName` seems to be the way to declare a property in the constructor (from what I've seen in docs) can you show me exactly what you mean if it's different

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Main extends React.Component<MainProps, MainState> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { todos: [], editorState: EditorState.createEmpty() };
        this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({ editorState });
    }

    onChange: (state: MainState) => void;

}
```

I haven't tested it, but I think it should work.

---

#### Edit

Yeah, there's a problem there that I haven't noticed, it should be:

```
class Main extends React.Component<MainProps, MainState> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { todos: [], editorState: EditorState.createEmpty() };
        this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({
            editorState: editorState
        } as MainState);
    }

    onChange: (state: MainState) => void;

}
```

The [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (`as MainState`) is needed if the `todos` property isn't optional, if it is optional (`todos?: any[]`) then there's no need for the assertion.

As for what seems to be duplication with the `onChange` definition, it is explained in short in the [Mixins part of the typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#understanding-the-sample), but in your example the definition in the class:

```
onChange: (state: MainState) => void;
```

let's the compiler know that instances of `Main` have this method called `onChange` that receives a `MainState` and returns `void`.
But the implementation of this method is only assigned when the instance is created in the ctor:

```
this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({ editorState });
```

If the definition is missing then the assignment in the ctor will produce a compilation error: `property 'onChange' does not exist on type 'Main'`.

Comment: regarding the `onChange` in the constructor in your code, the compiler says `MainState` is not assignable to type `EditorState`, so I assume that `this.setState({ editorState });` is attempting to implicitly assign `MainState` to the `editorState` property of the state object? Secondly, it's unclear to me why there's an onChange property in the constructor and also immediately following.

Comment: check my revised answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use handleChange method like this :

```html
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Editor, EditorState } from 'draft-js';

interface MyEditorProps {
}

class MyEditor extends React.Component<MyEditorProps, any> {
  constructor(props: MyEditorProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { editorState: EditorState.createEmpty() };
  }
  handleChange(e: EditorState) {
    this.setState({ editorState: e });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Editor editorState={this.state.editorState} onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyEditor />,
  document.getElementById('editor'),
);

export { MyEditor }
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can try it like this:

`private onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({ editorState } as MainState)`

just in the body of the class, where you define other class properties. I dunno, which version you're running, but this code totally works in `ES2015` and TypeScript `2.0.10`