# setState wants me to specify ALL properties of my state interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using React 15 and TypeScript 1.8.

My component's state object has multiple properties. I define an interface describing their types, write my component with `class MyComponent extends React.Component<any, MyStateInterface>`, set initial values for every property in the constructor method, it's all good.

The problem I have is when calling `this.setState` to update only one of my properties. TypeScript complains that I'm not setting *all* of them ("Property missing" error). I searched StackOverflow for a solution, and found others complaining of this, saying that the only solution was to simply declare all the fields optional.

However, that was an 18 month old answer, and I know both TypeScript and React move fast. I'm just wondering if this has changed in the last 500 days, and what the recommended practices are?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [allow typescript compiler to call setState on only one react state property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300933/allow-typescript-compiler-to-call-setstate-on-only-one-react-state-property)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I have is when calling this.setState to update only one of my properties. TypeScript complains that I'm not setting all of them

You should mark all of the members of the state as optional.

You might think this would be unsafe ... but because of freshness [more](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/freshness.html) it is still typechecked.