# Typescript & ReactJS How To Dynamically Set State

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I have this interface defined as my state:

```
interface State {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  dimensionID: string;
  file: File | null;
  operator: string;
  isFormValid: boolean;
  filename: string;
};
```

I have a simple on change handler:

```
  update = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    const { name, value } = event.currentTarget;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };
```

However, this error gets thrown:

```
Error:(109, 19) TS2345: Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'State | Pick<State, "id" | "name" | "description" | "dimensionID" | "file" | "operator" | "isFormValid" | "filename"> | ((prevState: Readonly<State>, props: Readonly<Props>) => State | Pick<...>)'.
  Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to type '(prevState: Readonly<State>, props: Readonly<Props>) => State | Pick<State, "id" | "name" | "description" | "dimensionID" | "file" | "operator" | "isFormValid" | "filename">'.
    Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: Readonly<State>, props: Readonly<Props>): State | Pick<State, "id" | "name" | "description" | "dimensionID" | "file" | "operator" | "isFormValid" | "filename">'.
```

My question is: How can I set state dynamically like how my on change handler tries?
This handler is used for different parts of the form so I won't know which key of state I will need to update.

**Update: SOLUTION**
From this [post](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948#issuecomment-412365629)

```
  update = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    const { name, value } = event.currentTarget;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }))
  };
```

Works!

Comment: bind the name where  ever you are calling update. `this.update.bind(null, name )`.  so that in the update function you have both name and event as parameters

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26635#issuecomment-400260278

Answer (score 3):

Most prefered solution casting.

```
this.setState({[name]: value} as {[P in keyof State]: State[P]})
// or
this.setState({[name]: value} as Pick<State, keyof State>)
```

setState with spread previous state

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
```

This doesn't check the types. It's just a quick workaround for anyone who is stuck transpiling.

```
this.setState<never>({[name]: value})
```

Related links

[React setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300933/allow-typescript-compiler-to-call-setstate-on-only-one-react-state-property)

[Github Tim Roes comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948#issuecomment-412365629)

Answer (score 2):

The constant **name** is widened to string. Which version of TS are you using?

You cast it like this, but it's not a good practice though:

```
this.setState({
  [name]: value
} as Pick<State, keyof State>);
```

Bug related to this issue:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15534
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948
- https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26635

Comment: Thanks for the links!

My solution came from the second link: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948#issuecomment-412365629

It seems this is the same issue I'm experiencing. It doesn't look like it was solved with the latest version, though. I'm using v3.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

eg.

```
update = (name: string, event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    const { value } = event.currentTarget;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

<input onChange={this.update.bind(null, 'first_name')} value={this.state.first_name} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in keyof` keywords to deconstruct the key / value from the IState object.

Create your React state:

```
interface IState { "email" : string; }
```

Create a form type that deconstruct the key as K and value as T[K]:

```
type FormState<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };
// T represents your IState
// to get the key use: [K in keyof T]
// to reference the value use: T[K]
```

Then pass the IState as a generic type  argument to FormState type:

```
FormState<IState>
```

Now you can update the state, casting it to the above FormState:

```
this.setState({ [formStateItem]: (e.target.value as any) } as FormState<IState>);
```

In a handler it might look like this:

```
handleChange = <T, K extends keyof IState>(formStateItem: K) => {
    return (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        this.setState({ [formStateItem]: (e.target.value as any) } as FormState<IState>);
    }
};
```

And finally you can use in you JSX like this:

```
onChange={this.handleChange("email")
```