# "No overload matches this call" TypeScript error when using setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

When I write the following code:

```
this.setState({ focus: true });
```

I get this error:

```
(property) State.focus: boolean
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(f: (prevState: State, props: Props) => State, callback?: () => any): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ focus: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(prevState: State, props: Props) => State'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'focus' does not exist in type '(prevState: State, props: Props) => State'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(state: State, callback?: () => any): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ focus: true; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'State'.
      Property 'error' is missing in type '{ focus: true; }' but required in type 'State'.ts(2769)
StripeField.tsx(88, 3): 'error' is declared here.
```

My state looks like this:

```
this.state = {
  focus: false,
  error: ''
};
```

The interface for my state is:

```
interface State {
  focus: boolean;
  error: string;
}
```

The error above goes away when I change my code to:

```
this.setState({ ...this.state, focus: true });
```

But my previous version is valid React code and is less verbose. Is there a way to use that version without TypeScript throwing this error?

Comment: Which version of TS are you using? according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37301050/4341456 should be fixed since 2.1

Comment: Did you tryusing the updater version of  `setState` ? `this.setState(prev=>({ ...prev, focus: true }))`

Comment: You either have to declare error property optional (`error?: string`) or to provide its value

Comment: @Daniel, OP would likely have to update his react types rather than typescript. OP, try npm i @types/react -D, then close and re-open your document in your text editor.