# What is the detail logic of type assertion in typescript?

Tags: typescript, type-assertion

I treat `type assertion` as something like `Hi Compiler, I know the type of this variable better than you. Just follow me!`.

But it seems that the compiler still has its own logic to infer the type. For example, suppose,

```
interface PM_MGEInfo {
    category: string;
    bid: string;
    cid?: string;
    labs?: { [key: string]: any };
}
```

Then, 1&2 are no problem, but 3 throws a TS2352 error.

1. ```
   function makeMgeInfo(bid: string): PM_MGEInfo {
       return <PM_MGEInfo>{
           bid
       };
   }
   ```
2. ```
   function makeMgeInfo(bid: string): PM_MGEInfo {
       return <PM_MGEInfo>{
           bid,
           labs: {}
       };
   }
   ```
3. ```
   function makeMgeInfo(bid: string): PM_MGEInfo {
       return <PM_MGEInfo>{
           bid,
           // error TS2352: Type '{ labs: { poi_id: string; }; bid: string; }' cannot be converted to type 'PM_MGEInfo'.
           // Property 'category' is missing in type '{ labs: { poi_id: string; }; bid: string; }'.
           labs: {a: 1}
       };
   }
   ```

Why does `type assertion` begin to check other fields in 3? Does someone know its detail logic?

---

Updated: I created an issue in Github [Microsoft/TypeScript#23698](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23698).

Comment: Sounds like a regression.

Comment: Yeah, it seem like a bug to me. If you declare a `PM_MGEInfo` variable, and you assign to it `{bid: 'o'}` it shows an error, saying `category` is missing. This should be the behaviour in 1) and 2). Don't know why it only triggers in case 3).

Comment: It appears that `{ [key: string]: any }` index signature triggers the error. I'd suggest to open an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the spec [4.16 Type Assertions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/28840863a635b6803505a821bcb18d9638c38012/doc/spec.md#4.16), which is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652622/why-does-typescript-assertion-of-object-literal-a-work-with-interface-a-b):

> In a type assertion expression of the form < T > e, e is contextually typed (section 4.23) by T and the resulting type of e is required to be assignable to T, or T is required to be assignable to the widened form of the resulting type of e, or otherwise a compile-time error occurs.

For case 1, `T` is assignable to `e` obviously.

For case 2, the widened form of `e` is `{bid: string, labs: Object}`, which T is assignable to. Notice that `labs?` is assignable to `Object` (*In fact, I am not sure about it, but this is my only possible explanation*).

For case 3, neither of above conditions is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options. Either use `Partial<T>` or `any`. When using any, YOU are responsible for making sure things will work, so use as last option.

Examples of both:

```
function makeMgeInfoWithPartial(bid: string): Partial<PM_MGEInfo> {
  // props are optional but only those defined by PM_MGEInfo are valid
  return {
    bid,
    labs: {a: 1}
  }
}

function makeMgeInfoWithAny(bid: string): PM_MGEInfo {
  return {
    bid,
    labs: {a: 1},
    whatever: 'also works'
  } as any
}
```

Comment: I agree with you that those options would make it work, but the question is WHY does it work that way .. adding the extra `labs` property should not have triggered the error.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir the TS2352 error was not caused by `labs`. The error message says `Property 'category' is missing in type`. Without `category`, that type was incomplete.

Comment: `category` is missing in this as well in `return <PM_MGEInfo>{
        bid } ` and this WORKS, only when adding `labs` do things break ..

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @TitianCernicova-Dragomir. I didn't see that earlier. hmm.. not sure why! hope someone else can. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the compiler doesn't recognize your value `{a: 1}` as type `{ [key: string]: any }` because if you alter the line like this there is no compiler error:

```
function makeMgeInfo(bid: string): PM_MGEInfo {
  return <PM_MGEInfo>{
    bid,
    labs: {a: 1} as {[key: string]: any}
  };
}
```

also it is working if you define the variable like this:

```
mylabs: {[key: string]: any} = {a: 1};
```

and call it in your function:

```
makeMgeInfo(bid: string): PM_MGEInfo {
  return <PM_MGEInfo>{
    bid,
    labs: this.mylabs
  };
}
```

Therefore I would say, that the compiler does not recognize your defined type from the labs field. The error message in this case is very misleading.