# Typescript class extending Partial interface

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a class that has all the properties of an interface, but does not actually declare those properties itself.The interface properties are appended during the build process and WILL exist at runtime.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36633639/typescript-partial-interface-object) that pointed me in the direction of using `Partial<T>`...but that doesn't seem to work. The following code produces no compile errors.

```js
interface Animal {
    name: string;
}

interface HasConstructor {
    constructor: any;
}
//Do this to supress this error: "Type 'Dog' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Animal>"
type OptionalAnimal = Partial<Animal> & HasConstructor;

class Dog implements OptionalAnimal {
    public constructor() {

    }
    public breed: string;
}
```

However, the `name` property is not available on the instance of Dog.

```js
var spot = new Dog();
spot.name = "Spot"; //ERROR: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Dog'
```

I can get around this issue by creating *another* type and referencing it like this:

```js
type AnimalDog = Dog & Animal;

var spot: Animal = new Dog() as any;
spot.name = "Spot";
```

However, I can't construct a new instance of `AnimalDog`, and have to cast as `any` to get the types to line up, so I'm left using both `AnimalDog` *and* `Dog` in my code depending on the scenario. This also produces compile errors inside of Dog when referencing Animal types.

Is there a way to tell typescript that the class implements the interface, without explicitly declaring every interface property?

Comment: What is the point `constructor: any` ? All objects have this property already ..\

Comment: `Is there a way to tell typescript that the class implements the interface, without explicitly declaring every interface property?` No. That's what classes are for, not interfaces. Interfaces DO NOT exist at runtime. Make a class instead of an interface and extend it instead of implementing it.

Comment: why is `Dog` a class at all? If you create everything during the build, let it be interface as well

Comment: @smnbbrv I don't create `everything` during the build, just tack on the missing parts from the interface. My example is not identical to our real-world scenario, but `Dog` has its own properties, and we actually need to run `new Dog()`, requiring a concrete instance of the class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that `Partial<T>` will only allow you to implement the members will not require you to do so, and if you don't implement the member it will not be in the class.

You can create a function that returns a class and this class will implement the interface. The returned class will not actually have to declare any of the fields so they will all be `undefined` but this should be fine since the fields have to be optional anyway.

```
interface Animal {
    name: string;
}

type OptionalAnimal = Partial<Animal>;
function autoImplement<T>(): new () => T {
    return class { } as any;
}
class Dog extends autoImplement<OptionalAnimal>() {
    public constructor() {
        super();
    }
    public breed: string;
}

var spot = new Dog();

spot.name = "Spot"; // ok now
```

You can also cast the `Dog` class to specify that the returned instance has the members of `Animal` but these new members will not be accessible from inside the class:

```
interface Animal {
    name: string;
}

class _Dog {
    public constructor() {

    }
    public breed: string;
}

const Dog = _Dog as { new(): _Dog & Partial<Animal> } & typeof _Dog
type Dog = InstanceType<typeof Dog>

var spot = new Dog();

spot.name = "Spot";
```

Comment: Your `autoImplment` solution does exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: I'd advise `autoImplement()` be defined so that it only allows `T` to be a [weak type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#weak-type-detection), at least with `--strictNullChecks` on.