# How to enforce object type with interface property - value

Tags: typescript

I have this interface

```
interface SUser {
  ID: number;
  NAME: string;
  MAIL: string;
  PASSWORD: string;
  GENDER: number;
  BIRTHDATE: string;
  ID_FB: string;
  CREDIT: number;
  ID_REFERRAL: number;
}
```

And I want to have a type describing an object and ensuring my object matches the key and value of one of my interface properties.

I tried the following :

```js
type fieldType = { [K in SUser]: string | number };
```

I set a field object to only allow a key from `SUser` ok, but I want to get an error if I set the value to a string if the key is `ID` for example.

Basically I want to enforce a key - value pair based on my interface.

With the previous code I get the following error, and value type is not enforced :

```
Type 'SUser' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
  Type 'SUser' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
```

Any help on this subject ?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. How do you expect to use `fieldType`? Also, types should be `TitleCase` for consistency

Comment: Should the field object have *exactly one* key/value pair from `SUser`?  Should it have *at least one* key/value pair from `SUser`?  It would be very useful for you to show examples of objects you'd like to succeed (e.g., `const good: fieldType = {...};`) and ones you'd like to fail (e.g., `const bad: fieldType = {...} // error!`).

Comment: Murat successfully answered my question ! Also thanks Juan for the type naming info :)

Comment: `type fieldType = Partial<SUser>` will allow any number of properties from `SUser`.  That means both `const x: fieldType = {}` (zero properties) and `const y: fieldType = {ID: 1, NAME: "x"}` (two properties) will compile.  Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use it like this

```
type fieldType = Partial<SUser>;
```

Comment: Is this not the same as `Partial<SUser>`?

Comment: Didn't know of the Partial utility type, thanks for that :)

Comment: Partial and what you had before (what I have in my answer) are not the same thing. A Partial makes all properties optional. It could be what the OP wanted, but the question is not clear enough since it doesn't show how it's going to be used.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code compile, you would do:

```
type fieldType = { [K in keyof SUser]: string | number };
```

But I'm not sure how you're going to use it since it would expand to:

```
type fieldType = {
  ID: string | number;
  NAME: string | number;
  MAIL: string | number;
  PASSWORD: string | number;
  GENDER: string | number;
  BIRTHDATE: string | number;
  ID_FB: string | number;
  CREDIT: string | number;
  ID_REFERRAL: string | number;
}
```

and that would not give you the error you want.

You may potentially want to use [Partial<SUser>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt) to create a type with all properties optional

```
type fieldType = {
  ID?: number;
  NAME?: string;
  MAIL?: string;
  PASSWORD?: string;
  GENDER?: number;
  BIRTHDATE: string;
  ID_FB?: string;
  CREDIT?: number;
  ID_REFERRAL?: number;
}
```

I'm assuming this is because you would like to pass in a subset of properties in some cases but in others, you require a full field. See [TypeScript partial interface object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36633639/typescript-partial-interface-object)