# How do you dynamically update a key-value pair on a typed object in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a function that takes in a key and a value and updates that corresponding key-value pair on a typed object. Here is a basic example of what I am after.

[Link to code sandbox with below code](https://codesandbox.io/s/xpjov)

```
type x = {
    prop : number,
    other : string
}

let dataToUpdate : x = {
    prop: 1,
    other: "string"
}

function updateKey(key : string, value : number | string) {
    dataToUpdate[key] = value;
}
```

I am getting this error with the above implementation.

> Element implicitly has an `'any'` type because expression of type `'string'` can't be used to index type `'x'`.
> No index signature with a parameter of type `'string'` was found on type `'x'`.(7053)

**Update**
I was introduced to the idea of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/254800). Below is the actual implementation I am after. I am trying to create a context within React that returns a function that allows you to only update a specific property within the object that is stored in the context

```
export function StoreProvider(props: any) {
    const [storeData, setStoreData] = useState<StoreData>(initProviderData);

    function setStoreKeyValue(keyToUpdate: keyof StoreData[], valueToSet: boolean | string | number | null){
        let newStoreData = {...storeData);
        const isStoreData = Object.keys(initProviderData).filter((key) => { key == keyToUpdate }).length > 1;

        if (isStoreData && newStoreData) {
            newStoreData[keyToUpdate] = valueToSet;
            setStoreData(newStoreData)
        }
    }

    return (
        <StoreContext.Provider value={{ "storeData": storeData, "setStoreData": setStoreData }}>
            {props.children}
        </StoreContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Comment: First, there's no reason for the `key` to ever be a number.

Comment: I removed all irrelevant tags, but since you had listed reactjs, I guess this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/254800) and you really should be asking about the real situation you're trying to solve instead of the roadblock you're facing with typings right now.

Comment: @EmileBergeron That's a fair point. Thanks for sharing that, I have updated the post with the actual implementation within React that I am trying to solve

Comment: Nice edit! Next thing I see: `newStoreData[keyToUpdate]` is [mutating the current `storeData` object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43638938/1218980), which is an [anti-pattern as this state should stay immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37760774/1218980).

Comment: Quick JS tip: `value={{ storeData, setStoreData }}` is enough if the variable name and the key is the same. It's the [Object initializer property shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34414766/1218980).

Comment: That said, instead of a `key` and `value` params, you could consider an object param with the [`Partial<StoreData>` type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36633639/1218980)?

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to avoid modifying the storeData object, but realize now that I was! Using the spread operator seems to be a better way of cloning the object. I'll give Partial<T> a go and see what I can come up with. Thanks for all of the help!

Comment: just because I don't see mentioned, the correct signature of such a function is `updateKey<K extends keyof x>(key: K, value: x[K])`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thank you! Please post your answer so I can mark it as the best answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TLDR**;

```
updateKey<K extends keyof X>(key: K, value: X[K]) {
  dataToUpdate[key] = value; 
}
```

**Details**:

Given

```
type X = {
  prop: number;
  other: string;
};

const dataToUpdate: X = {
    prop: 1,
    other: "string"
};
```

TypeScript does not allow us to access properties of a well-typed object with a known set of properties, such as your `dataToUpdate`, via an arbitrary property key type such as `string`.

As the language knows that the only keys of `dataToUpdate` are `"prop"` and `"other"`, the key parameter of your update function must be restricted accordingly.

While we could write out the union type explicitly in the parameter list,  `key: "prop" | "other"`, this pattern is so fundamental to JavaScript that TypeScript provides the `keyof` type operator which produces a union type of all the property keys of a given type, allowing us to write

```
updateKey(key: keyof X, value: string | number) {
  dataToUpdate[key] = value; 
}
```

However, we're not done yet because the language needs to ensure that the type of the `value` parameter corresponds to the property type of the specified `key` and, as it happens, `"prop"` must be a `number` and `"other"` must be a `string`.

To describe this we adjust our declaration as follows

```
updateKey<K extends keyof X>(key: K, value: X[K])
```

What we've done is associate the types of the two parameters such that the type of `value` matches the type of the property specified by `key`, whenever the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @Aluan is absolutely correct but there is another way also. Just add the dynamic key to your type as below:

```
type x = {
    prop : number,
    other : string,
    [key: string]: string | number;
}
```

Comment: While this technically solves for the type x case, it is not as extendable when you start working with more complex types. In my case, I have a type with several keys that all vary in type, so you can end up essentially allowing for an implicit type of `any` in this case. @Aluan Haddad's response allows for any number & type of keys without losing the strict typing of your parameters

Comment: I agree to you Shawn. This even works with required fields only.