# Typescript alternative to Java <? super SomeType>

Tags: java, typescript

Have a specific use-case where one of the generic params that are used to instantiate my class should be a superclass of another class, in java this is easily doable via <? super SomeType>

What would the alternative in typescript be?

Comment: seems to have been solved with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50443429/1840146

Comment: Use `T<any>` (or if you want to be more strict `T<unknown>` or `T<never>`  if you want to be more strict,  but with those you need to think about variance, and they will not work for an invariant type)

Answer (score 0):

`<E extends Partial<SomeType>>`  is the closest we can get with typescript